# Phone no. display on Android pie?

Tags: privacy, 9.0-pie

I am having Asus zenfone max pro M1,  now updated to android pie recently. Previousely the phone came with default  Oreo OS. 
After checking the features of new OS , i have found out that the OS  has detected my phone no. and is also displaying it.  Before in  oreo OS it wasn't displayed or AFAIK it wasn't known to google.

My question is - isn't this is a privicy breach or google was already aware of it in oreo also , only  the no. was not  displayed?

Comment: There is a sub-permission under READ_PHONE_STATE permission that permits reading phone number. The new update probably has  a system app (most likely Settings app) which uses this permission.

Comment: @Firelord - Yes the number is displayed in settings app. :-)